# ffmpeg time unit explanation and av_seek_frame method

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

What does `time_base` mean in ffmpeg? document([here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/data.html#AVStream)) says it is "frames per second".
and I see in a real example that:

`AVFormatContext->streams[video_index]->time_base` == *1 / 30000*

But video's `AVCodecContext->time_base` == *1001 / 60000*

This makes me quite confused, and I don't understand them.

The second question is about **av_seek_frame** method.
If seeking via time stamp (last parameter is AVSEEK_FLAG_BACKWARD or 0),
the seek is started from current position read by **av_seek_frame**?
or from the start of the file? or from the start position of decoding after last **av_seek_frame** call ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But video's AVCodecContext->time_base == 1001 / 60000
>
> This makes me quite confused, and I don't understand them.

time_base is of type AVRational, which is a rational number composed of a numerator and a denominator, as opposed to using a decimal point. I assume the reason they don't just use double is that this way you don't lose any precision.

AVRational is defined in the sources as:

```
typedef struct AVRational{
    int num; ///< numerator
    int den; ///< denominator
} AVRational;
```

time_base is also reciprocal to frames per second, not equal to it. So if you have 30 fps, this means that time base is 1/30, instead of 30.

Comment: thanks,  I understood the AVRational, and the question is about time_base. why are they different, you see the streams[video_index]->time_base is different from AVCodecContext's time_base. actually they are related to the same video stream, this makes me very confused.

Comment: Ah, I see. See [this link](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2011-December/001041.html), may be it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use r_frame_rate, since it is libavformats guess, not exact. (see http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2005-May/003079.html )

AVCodecContext.time_base gives the exact fps. If ticks_per_frame is 2, downsize the time_base with 1/2. For example, if AVCodecContext.time_base (1, 60) and ticks_per_frame is 1, the fps is 60. If ticks_per_frame is 2, fps is 30.

If AVCodecContext->time_base is (1001, 60000), fps is 60.

The time_base for AVCodecContext is related to fps.

The time_base for AVStream is only for time unit in the methods in AVStream, such as getting the time of one frame, or the .start variable.

There is another time_base for AVPacket. But from ffmpeg-devel, they prefer to make AVPacket.time_base the same as the one for AVStream.

Answer (score 2):

I tested all of the fields from satuon's comment link with a number of video files, and it appears as though the correct framerate can be calculated thus:

`double framerate = av_q2d(pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->r_frame_rate);`

... where `pFormatCtx` is your AVFormatContext and `videoStream` is the index of your video stream, found using this code:

```
int videoStream = -1;
for (uint i=0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO && videoStream < 0) {
        videoStream = i;
    }
}
```

Using ffmpeg 1.1.